# Delimitate container width from the parent

Tags: css

I'm new in css and I'm working in section with a simple circle and in the middle of the circle I added an svg image and at the bottom of the circle I add a simple text

Code:

```css
  .treatment-method__title{
    margin-top: 4em;
    color:#0e4f1f;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .treatment-method__title__complement{
    text-align: center;
  }
  .treatment-methods__icons {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .treatment-method__icon__container {
    flex: 1 0 21%;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  .treatment-method__icon__outer_circle {
    background-color: #0e4f1f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  
  .treatment-methods_icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    /* border-radius: 50%; */
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .treatment-methods__icon__text{
    color:#0e4f1f;
     margin-top: 4em;
  }
```

```html
<section class="treatment-methods">
                  <h1 class="treatment-method__title">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet</h1>
                  <p class="treatment-method__title__complement">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet</p>
                  <div class="treatment-methods__icons">
                    <div class="treatment-method__icon__container">
                      <div class="treatment-method__icon__outer_circle">
                        <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80293/online.svg" alt="wellness" class="treatment-methods_icon">
                            <p class="treatment-methods__icon__text">Psicoterapy</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="treatment-method__icon__container">
                      <div class="treatment-method__icon__outer_circle">
                        <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80293/online.svg" alt="wellness" class="treatment-methods_icon">
                            <p class="treatment-methods__icon__text">Psicoterapy</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="treatment-method__icon__container">
                      <div class="treatment-method__icon__outer_circle">
                        <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80293/online.svg" alt="wellness" class="treatment-methods_icon">
                            <p class="treatment-methods__icon__text">Psicoterapy</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="treatment-method__icon__container">
                      <div class="treatment-method__icon__outer_circle">
                        <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80293/online.svg" alt="wellness" class="treatment-methods_icon">
                            <p class="treatment-methods__icon__text">Psicoterapy</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                
                  </div>
              </section>
```

Problem is that all my circles have 100% width of the width container of the page and I want to change this to be only inside the title above as:

[image]

How can I delimitate the area of that circles to be between my two bars? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with `align item` and `justify-content` to make your `section` stay in the center of the screen and for title and circles add a div called `title_icons` and used `display:inline-block`.

Your `circles` will be within (center) of the text `blocks` and will be responsive as well.

**Live Demo:**

```css
.treatment-method__title {
  margin-top: 4em;
  color: #0e4f1f;
  text-align: center;
}

.treatment-method__title__complement {
  text-align: center;
}

.treatment-methods__icons {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  text-align: center;
}

.treatment-method__icon__container {
  flex: 1 0 21%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
}

.treatment-method__icon__outer_circle {
  background-color: #0e4f1f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.treatment-methods_icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  color: #ffffff;
}

.treatment-methods__icon__text {
  color: #0e4f1f;
  margin-top: 4em;
}

.title_icons {
  display: inline-block;
}

.treatment-methods {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="treatment-methods">
  <div class="title_icons">

    <h1 class="treatment-method__title">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet</h1>
    <p class="treatment-method__title__complement">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet</p>
    <div class="treatment-methods__icons">
      <div class="treatment-method__icon__container">
        <div class="treatment-method__icon__outer_circle">
          <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80293/online.svg" alt="wellness" class="treatment-methods_icon">
          <p class="treatment-methods__icon__text">Psicoterapy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="treatment-method__icon__container">
        <div class="treatment-method__icon__outer_circle">
          <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80293/online.svg" alt="wellness" class="treatment-methods_icon">
          <p class="treatment-methods__icon__text">Psicoterapy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="treatment-method__icon__container">
        <div class="treatment-method__icon__outer_circle">
          <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80293/online.svg" alt="wellness" class="treatment-methods_icon">
          <p class="treatment-methods__icon__text">Psicoterapy</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="treatment-method__icon__container">
        <div class="treatment-method__icon__outer_circle">
          <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80293/online.svg" alt="wellness" class="treatment-methods_icon">
          <p class="treatment-methods__icon__text">Psicoterapy</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```